# How to delete rows in Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel

I would like to delete some rows in my Excel's file with Python.

[File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LlNx.png)

In fact the interesting part for my use begins Row 6 with "30". I'm looking for a good way to delete the rows that are above.

How should I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to use Pandas, then try this:

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", skiprows=list(range(5)))
```

Here using `skiprows` will not read in the first 5 rows, then if you want to save it as an excel file:

```
table.to_excel("new_file.xlsx")
```

Comment: But I would like an automatic detection. Every files are different, sometimes I have some "noise" on the 10 first rows and sometimes I don't have rows to delete..

Comment: Is there any similar pattern in the rows you don't need? A general approach is read in the whole file, filter out the rows you don't need by detecting the patterns and save it as a new file